# Is having an identity primary key in addition to a composite unique constraint redundant?

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key

I have a table that has an identity column as the primary key as well as unique constraint on both the identity column + a second column:

```
CREATE TABLE Variable
(
    VariableId BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
    CalcId BIGINT NOT NULL,
)
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CL_CalcId_VariableId ON Variable(CalcId,VariableId)
```

I then have a second table that also has an identity primary key, as well as two of the same fields as the first table that act as foreign keys:

```
CREATE TABLE Value
(
    ValueId BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
    CalcId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    VariableId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (CalcId,VariableId) REFERENCES Variable(CalcId, VariableId)
)
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CL_CalcId_VariableId_ValueId ON Value(CalcId,VariableId,ValueId)
```

Is this design redundant?

Since VariableId is an identity in the first table, I don't really need my foreign key to have CalcId and VariableId in the second table. I am thinking of building the tables this way though because the combination of CalcId+VariableId is what "makes sense" to describe a unique record but having an identity column makes it easier to write queries that update/delete a single row - just not sure if this over-complicating the design.

Any thoughts would be appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: Some example data:

```
VariableId  | CalcId
---------------------
1           | 1
2           | 1
3           | 1
4           | 2
5           | 2

ValueId | VariableId    | CalcId
---------------------------------
1       | 1             | 1
2       | 1             | 1
3       | 2             | 1
4       | 3             | 1
5       | 4             | 2
6       | 4             | 2
7       | 5             | 2
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data to illustrate what you are trying to do?

Comment: The unique constraint on the 1st table is logically wrong because the `VariableId` is already unique and adding a 2nd column will not make it "more unique". Is the `CalcId` supposed to be unique?

Comment: CalcId is not supposed to unique.  Just in terms of thinking about how the data gets used, a CalcId and VariableId always go hand in hand.

Comment: So drop the additional Unique constraint and simply use the single column PK as reference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in most cases, the answer is **it depends**.

Keeping an identity column as a surrogate key along side with a composite unique index is a good idea when you are using the key of the table as a foreign key to other tables. it simplifies your database connections and make your joins easier to write, read and maintain.

However, if your table is not referenced by other tables, then there really is not much sense in adding a surrogate key.

Also, as dnoeth wrote in his comment, there is no point of making a composite unique index when what of it's parts is already unique.

Comment: I cannot write it in a better way, I was writing an answer just because that surrogate key. The only justification here to create a composite unique index in the second table is if OP wants to enforce integrity (if he got concerns about the app using the DB can do some kind of mistake for example creating a redundant record).