# Do I really need an identity field on Bridge Tables?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

Do I really need an extra identity field say called `id` on a bridge table?  For primary tables I set an id and have it start incrementing from 0.  But not sure about bridge tables.

Example:

```
user
  user_id (identity)
  name

user_communities
  id (identity) - do I even need this??
  user_id
  community_id

communities
  community_id (identity)
  name
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is having an identity primary key in addition to a composite unique constraint redundant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31830569/is-having-an-identity-primary-key-in-addition-to-a-composite-unique-constraint-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need an additional generated primary key on a bridge table - at least not if `(user_id, community_id)` is the primary key.

You would only need it in case you would allow a user to participate in the same community multiple times, e.g. with different roles.

Answer (score 2):

Your relationship links two entities, thus you have the ids of the two entities in it. In that case the id in your bridge table is unnecessary.

But, although rarer, you could also have higher order relationships which connect two relationships or a relationship with other entities. Say, for example, you want to qualify a relationship with a set of properties (the strength of the relationship, its participants, etc), you could have a relationship properties table that links to the relationship (thus you would need its id) to a set of name-values pairs. You could even have a bridge table between two different bridge tables to connect them and assign certain properties to the connection (which relationship has priority over the other, e.g.)